# Spark JDBC - How to stop automatic creation of table if table doesnt exist

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jdbc

I'm currently using jdbc to write data into an existing table.

```
jdbcDF.write
  .mode(Savemode.append)
  .jdbc("jdbc:postgresql:dbserver", "schema.tablename", connectionProperties)
```

I'm currently using code similar to above. When given a wrong table name, it will create that table and input that table there as opposed to throwing an error. Is there anyway to stop that feature.

Comment: I don't think there is a config or flag for exactly this purpose, I think best way is to add a simple check(if the table exist or not) and save accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is not supported by Spark. Your would need to write your own logic around it.

According to the [ScalaDocs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SaveMode.html) on Enumeration `SaveMode` you have the following options when writing Data to a sink:

- **Append**: Append mode means that when saving a DataFrame to a data source, if data/table already exists, contents of the DataFrame are expected to be appended to existing data.
- **ErrorIfExists**: ErrorIfExists mode means that when saving a DataFrame to a data source, if data already exists, an exception is expected to be thrown.
- **Ignore**: Ignore mode means that when saving a DataFrame to a data source, if data already exists, the save operation is expected to not save the contents of the DataFrame and to not change the existing data.
- **Overwrite**: Overwrite mode means that when saving a DataFrame to a data source, if data/table already exists, existing data is expected to be overwritten by the contents of the DataFrame.